# If I await 2 functions can I guarantee that the return object will have both values

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have the following code

```
module.exports = async function (req, res) {
 const station1 = await getStation('one')
 const station2 = await getStation('two')

 return { stations: [station1, station2] }
}
```

Can I be guaranteed that when the final return value is sent it will definitely have both `station1` and `station2` data in them, or do I need to wrap the function call in a `Promise.all()`

Comment: You use `Promise.all` only if you want to resolve them in parallel.

Comment: In this case, since you have no dependencies between station1 and 2, it's recommended to run them parallel and waiting for them using `Promise.all`.

Comment: @AmirPopovich would that look like something like  
 `const [station1, station2] = await Promise.all([getStation('one'), getStation('two')])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have it, it is guaranteed that the `return` statement will only be executed when the two `getStation()` promises have resolved.

However, the second call to `getStation` will only happen when the first promise has resolved, making them run in serial. As there is no dependency between them, you could gain performance, if you would run them in parallel.

Although this can be achieved with `Promise.all`, you can achieve the same by first retrieving the two promises and only then performing the `await` on them:

```
module.exports = async function (req, res) {
    const promise1 = getStation('one');
    const promise2 = getStation('two');
    return { stations: [await promise1, await promise2] }
}
```

Now both calls will be performed at the "same" time, and it will be just the `return` statement that will be pending for both promises to resolve. This is also illustrated in [MDN's "simple example"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Simple_example).

Comment: Are you sure the calls will be performed at the same time? It's not shown in the MDN example you link and [a simple test](https://jsfiddle.net/qry3t1L4/) suggests that multiple `await`s in one statement are run sequentially.

Comment: @lonesomeday, yes, I tested it. Note the two variants of the code that are presented on MDN, and the difference in the number of seconds it takes for the output.

Comment: But the `add1` function there sets up the two promises and *then* awaits them, which is different from what you do here. See the example linked in my previous comment.

Comment: I see your point. I have adapted it to be in line with the *add2* example on MDN.

Answer (score 1):

The await keyword actually makes you "wait" on the line of code, while running an async action.

That means that you don't proceed to the next line of code until the async action is resolved. This is good if your code has a dependency with the result.

Example:

```
const res1 = await doSomething();
if(res1.isValid)
{
   console.log('do something with res1 result');
}
```

The following code example will await a promise that gets resolved after three seconds. Check the date prints to the console to understand what await does:

```
async function f1() {
  console.log(new Date());

  // Resolve after three seconds
  var p = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({}),3000);
  });

  await p;

  console.log(new Date());
}

f1();
```

[ES6Console](https://es6console.com/j0rv6fgz/)

BTW, In your case, since you don't use the result of `station1` it's better using `Promise.all` to work parallel.

Check this example (it will run for 3 seconds instead of 4 seconds the way you coded above):

```
async function f1() {
  console.log(new Date());

  // Resolve after three seconds
  var p1 = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({a:1}),3000);
  });

  // Resolve after one second
  var p2 = new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve({a:2}),1000);
  });

  // Run them parallel - Max(three seconds, one second) -> three seconds.
  var res = await Promise.all([p1,p2]);

  console.log(new Date());

  console.log('result:' + res);
}

f1();
```

[ES6Console](https://es6console.com/j0rvew8a/).

Comment: would that look like something like  
 `const [station1, station2] = await Promise.all([getStation('one'), getStation('two')])`

Comment: Yes. Check my edit, I've added an example + explanation why it's faster.

Comment: If I had to call `p1` & `p2` with arguments would that still work ok?

Comment: A promise is a promise. I've added a simple promise that only waits and returns a hard coded object result. You can do things with params.

Comment: Ah ok that makes sense I was just unsure if calling the function immediately would cause an issue thankyou very much

Answer (score 1):

If either of `await getStation('one')` or `await getStation('two')` fails an exception will be thrown from the async function. So you should always get the resolved value from both promises.

You can rewrite your function as follows to use `Promise.all`

```
module.exports = async function (req, res) {
 try{

     const [station1, station2] = await Promise.all([
      getStation('one'),
      getStation('two')
     ]);

     return { stations: [station1, station2] };

  } catch (e) {
      throw e;
  }
}
```